# Linq: Best way to select parent rows order by count of children

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a table for Comments like following:

```
Comment{  
ID,  
Text,  
ParentID  
}
```

I am using following query to select the popular comments with paging based on number of replies.

```
var comments = db.Comments
.OrderByDescending(c => db.Comments.Count(r => r.ParentID == c.ID)).Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage).ToList();
```

Please let me know the best way of handling this situation when we have thousands of comments?

Comment: have you consider adding an extra column to `Comment` that stores replies count ?

Comment: I think you're skipping and taking before ordering, which could give you wrong results.

Comment: @drw8 you might be right i think. I will see whether my original code is like that.

Comment: I don't know what's best. You set the premises. If the count performs well enough, go for it. Generally, database engines are good at counting records. Storing redundant counts is an option, but it takes a lot of maintenance to keep them in sync with the real counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider adding an extra column to `Comment` that stores the replies count.Then instead making a nested query you can easily order your `Comments` by replies count.

```
var comments = db.Comments.Skip(skip).Take(recordsPerPage)
                 .OrderByDescending(c => c.ReplyCount)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I have considered adding a column but then I have to re-calculate the ReplyCount every time a reply is moderated, flagged or deleted.. That is again a kind of overhead, so i was thinking if there is a best way using linq.

Comment: I understand but it shouldn't be a overhead,you just need to update one comments reply count every time a reply is moderated, flagged or deleted.. I think this is reasonable as compared in your current situation

Comment: I think I will do a ReplyCount for now unless someone posts a better & easy approach.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are prepared to pre-calculate this in the database then you have the problem that you need to either do nested queries or to do a single full fetch an then do everything in memory. The latter is my choice until it is proven to be too slow.

Here's how I'd initially do it.

First, pre-fetch:

```
var allComments = Comments.ToArray();
```

Then create a function that will quickly return the count of comments:

```
var childrenLookup = allComments.ToLookup(x => x.ParentID);
var parentMap = allComments.ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.ParentID);

Func<int, int> getCommentsCount = n =>
{
    var r = 0;
    if (parentMap.ContainsKey(n))
    {
        r = childrenLookup[parentMap[n]].Count();
    }
    return r;
};
```

Now it is almost trivial to return the results:

```
var comments = allComments
    .OrderByDescending(c => getCommentsCount(c.ID))
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(recordsPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

(And, yes, your ordering is in the wrong order to you skip and take for paging.)

If you can't do this in memory then go with the pre-calculate approach.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think I will pre-calculate for this project but surely will keep this approach into consideration. thanks!!